# How can I get a HTML5 video in phonegap to appear in a div ( not fullscreen )

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

I have a video on a page in my phonegap app that uses the html5 video tag

```
<video src="video.mp4" id="player" webkit-playsinline>
</video>
```

but when I click on the video it turns into a fullscreen video player, I want it to appear like it would on a normal webpage as I need to display other content underneath the video while it plays, how can I do this?